# How to test child component @output

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I would like to test a child component @output in angular2. I want to use this mock child component @output to activate a parent component function and test it.

Mock the component and test all the async method.

```html
<wizard-quick-search-page *ngIf="initSearchPanel" [createUserAttributes]="createUserAttributes" [existingUserAttributes]="existingUserAttributes" (edit)="showEditUserPanel($event)"
  (create)="showCreateUserPanel($event)">
</wizard-quick-search-page>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'wizard-quick-search-page',
  template: '<button class="quick-search-page-submit" (click)="onClick()">Create</button>'
})
class MockQuickSearchPageComponent {
  @Output() public create: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  public onClick(): void {
    console.log('call create');
    this.create.emit(true);
  }
}

fdescribe('AddUserComponent', () => {
  let component: AddUserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddUserComponent>;
  let mockQuickSearchComponent: MockQuickSearchPageComponent;
  let mockQuickSearchComponentFixture: ComponentFixture<MockQuickSearchPageComponent>;
  let createButton: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: Language, useClass: MockLanguage }
      ],
      declarations: [
        AddUserComponent,
        MockQuickSearchPageComponent
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddUserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('quickSearchComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      mockQuickSearchComponentFixture = TestBed.createComponent(MockQuickSearchPageComponent);
      mockQuickSearchComponent = mockQuickSearchComponentFixture.componentInstance;
      mockQuickSearchComponentFixture.detectChanges();

      createButton = mockQuickSearchComponentFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button.quick-search-page-submit'));
    });

    it('should create', () => {
      expect(mockQuickSearchComponent).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should open create a new user panel', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'showCreateUserPanel');
      createButton.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
      tick();
      mockQuickSearchComponentFixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.showCreateUserPanel).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
  });
});
```

Parent component function component.showCreateUserPanel not been called

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to test how parent and child communicate to each other then you shouldn't create isolated instance of `MockQuickSearchPageComponent` but rather use the instance which is initialized within parent component.

**Current test**

```
AddUserComponent  MockQuickSearchPageComponent
```

In your implementation they know nothing about each other.

> **TestBed.createComponent(MockQuickSearchPageComponent);** creates a new component tree with MockQuickSearchPageComponent as a root component

**How it should be done**

```
 AddUserComponent  
       ||
       \/
MockQuickSearchPageComponent
```

Now `MockQuickSearchPageComponent` is a child of `AddUserComponent` and can listen for any events emmited from that child component.

It could be done by using `fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MockQuickSearchPageComponent)`:

```
describe('quickSearchComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture.componentInstance.initSearchPanel = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const childDirQueryResult = 
             fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MockQuickSearchPageComponent));

    mockQuickSearchComponent = childDirQueryResult.componentInstance;

    createButton = childDirQueryResult.query(By.css('button.quick-search-page-submit'));
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(mockQuickSearchComponent).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should open create a new user panel', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'showCreateUserPanel');
    createButton.triggerEventHandler('click', null);

    expect(component.showCreateUserPanel).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/qAG0soTouH6Vf3P9)**

Comment: Thanks, it is really clear for me. Now, I know what is the problem for me. Not familar with angular unit test parent and child component structure there.

Comment: There is actually a slightly easier way to do this. You do not need to have the mock component have a button and hook up the click event. You can just declare the output, and you can reference it once you have the component instance. 

const childDirQueryResult =              fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MockQuickSearchPageComponent)).componentInstance;

childDirQueryResult.create.emit('your value to emit');

Comment: it's a time consuming when adopt this solution, what if the child component have a bunch of content, i don't care to mock all of it, so it's very bad to do that, instead you can trigger the output with triggerEventHandler and spyOn for the wanted function, then do your assertion ...